# SSIS Transformation: SQL Sub Query into SSIS Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to dive deep into "Transformation" part of ETL using SSIS. I need to achieve a task done via SQL Query (Stored Proc) using a SSIS Task.

The output is to produce Top 5 triplets with their percentage contribution. I have simulated what I am doing in SQL Stored Proc.

Can you please guide me how do I that.

```
--Preparing Dataset
CREATE TABLE temp20190716
    (
        WeekNumber INT,
        Triplet VARCHAR(50),
        Product VARCHAR(50) ,
        CustomerType VARCHAR(50),
        Occurence INT
    )

INSERT INTO temp20190716
    (
    WeekNumber ,
    Triplet ,
    Product ,
    CustomerType ,
    Occurence 
    )
VALUES 
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4) ,'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4) ,'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4) ,'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4) ,'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Mobile','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),

    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),       
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),       
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10) ,
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),       
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10) ,
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),       
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10),
    (201915,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4)+':'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),0,4),'Fixed','Consumer',FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10)
```

Need to achive below output using SSIS

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(SELECT TOP 5
    Triplet,
    SUM(Occurence)Sort,
    Triplet+', '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(Occurence))+', '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(Occurence)*100/(SELECT SUM(Occurence) FROM temp20190716 WHERE Product IN ('Mobile') AND CustomerType='Consumer' ))+' %' DisplayName,
    'Consumer Mobile' Tag ,
    CustomerType
FROM temp20190716
WHERE Product IN ('Mobile') AND CustomerType='Consumer'
GROUP BY Triplet ,CustomerType
ORDER BY 2 DESC
UNION 
SELECT TOP 5
    Triplet,
    SUM(Occurence)Sort,
    Triplet+', '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(Occurence))+', '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(Occurence)*100/(SELECT SUM(Occurence) FROM temp20190716 WHERE Product IN ('Fixed') AND CustomerType='Consumer' ))+' %' DisplayName,
    'Consumer Fixed' Tag ,
    CustomerType
FROM temp20190716
WHERE Product IN ('Fixed') AND CustomerType='Consumer'
GROUP BY Triplet ,CustomerType
ORDER BY 2 DESC
)X
```

Output in SQL:

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use the stored proc from SSIS? I would always go that path myself as I find it much simpler and more maintainable.

Comment: @TomC I completely agree to you but the my Manager says that Transformation should be done in SSIS itself. So, just my exploring my options in SSIS as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your manager absolutely won't let you use the best practice of running that query as a stored proc, you can work around the limitation in two ways, depending on how you want to use your data.

Option #1: Use your query as a Source Connection. You can create an `OLE DB Source` in a `Data Flow Task` that uses a query instead of a table/view. It would look something like this:

[image]

Option #2: Use your query in an `Execute SQL Task` in your `Control Flow`. In your `Execute SQL Task` you'd set the `ResultSet` property to `Full Result Set` and map it to a variable of type Object. You could then use that object the same way you would any other dataset object. This would be the preferred solution if you needed to process each row iteratively, like in a `Foreach Loop`.